# User that jenkins uses is not part of a group when jenkins job is run

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Jenkins 2.46.2.

Ubuntu 14.04

Jenkins is using user `www-data`.

```
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7967754688382064194.sh
+ whoami
www-data
Finished: SUCCESS
```

When I ssh into the instance and switch to user `www-data` and check what groups does it belong to I can see `docker` group.

```
$ id
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),998(docker)
```

When I check what groups does user belong yo by running a Jenkins job I cannot see `docker`.

```
sh("id")
//output:
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Because of this I cannot execute docker commands. Why is this group missing in this case?

Comment: Are you sure that jenkins is executed by "www-data" user?

Comment: @DurdenP I updated the post. When I run `whoami` it will say `www-data`. Alos jenkins process belongs to www-data. And workspace and JENKINS_HOME belongs to user www-data.

Comment: @raitisd Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Jenkins as a service using Apt, Jenkins is running as jenkins user. Do the following:

```
$usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Comment: I am not sure how this Jenkins was installed. Jenkins is using user `www-data` in this case. And if I ssh I can see that this user is part of `docker` group.

Comment: Jenkins runs as a Java .jar archive. If you do `ps -aef | grep java` the jar is run as jenkins user. Jenkins user is not used to ssh into the system. Add jenkins user to docker group and it would work.

Comment: Nope, on this machine its running as www-data user. User `jenkins` also exists on the instance but is not used. I added it to docker group at the very beginning before i discovered that www-data is used. So, both users `jenkins` and `www-data` are added to `docker` group. The problem is that when Jenkins job is run then the user is not part of the group somehow.

Comment: Did you restart jenkins after adding the user to docker group?

Comment: I restarted Jenkins via browser `jenkinsurl.com/restart`. I dont have a way to restart the instance it self. I might have a way to restart Jenkins from command like tho, with `service jenkins restart` or smtn like that.

Comment: For a test, could you try adding the user to the group in a jenkins job. And then check whether it shows up in the group.

Comment: user www-data does not have permissions to run `usermod`